# Get the text of <a> in <li> when a button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

Hello I am building a feedback form with a custom rating list which looks like this:

```
<ul class="star-rating" id="rating">
  <li><a href="#" class="one-star">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="two-stars" >2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="buttonNext btn btn-success">Next</a>
```

When the user selects clicks the rating i have the next button in which i do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success').click(function() {
            var text = $("#rating li a").text();
            alert("Text: " + text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

But in the alert i get Text: 12345.

What am i doing wrong and not getting the correct text?

How will i be able to get only 3 if user clicked 3 and so on?

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Where is the `$('.buttonNext')` element?

Comment: `$("#rating li a")` is the problem. This selector will select all the `a` elements inside all `li` elements. That's why you are getting all of the values.

Comment: how can i solve this? Even if i put #rating li it gets all the elements

Comment: Where is the $('.buttonNext') element? (2). You are not responding to this.

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan it is just a button from jQuery smartwizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul#rating li a').click(function() {
      $('ul li a').removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success').click(function() {
      var text = $("#rating li a.active").text();
      alert("Text: " + text);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="star-rating" id="rating">
  <li><a href="#" class="one-star">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="buttonNext">
  Submit
</button>
```

Demo : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x6fad5x/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate which rating is selected, for instance with selected class.

```
$('#rating li').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   return false;
});
```

and then you will be able to get the selected rating with

```
$('#rating li.selected a').text();
```

Comment: the first part where exactly should i place it?

Comment: @BRG in the same place where is your code, in document ready.